# Is there a parser for solving equation with unknowns in AForge Genetic .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, aforge

I have to find parser for solving equation with unknows. User enters two numbers and the parser parses equation to solve. For example:

Equation:
x^3 + y^2 + sin60°

User input:
x=4, y=2

It have to be done using AForge.NET framework. Console app/WinForms

I have been looking for it in AForge .NET documentation but can't find something matches my problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi! Please provide more details for the type of equation, how it is input and what should be solved for. A simple example would go a long way to make this an answerable question. Also, must the solution be specific to `AForge.NET` or other numerical libraries would suffice? Finally, is this to be a Console/WinForms/WPF/MAUI/ASPNET app? And is it .NET Framework or .NET ~Core~.

Comment: If `x` and `y` are given, then you are not looking for a _solution_, but for a _evaluation_ of a function. A solution would be finding an unknown, and it involves either algebraic manipulations or numerical approximations. Your example seems like a straight forward application of an expression parser with evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is an evaluator for regular mathematical expressions in AForge, but you could use the [PolishExpression](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/fa3baf92-51e6-f270-4a00-6e36323de436.htm) class to evaluate an expression written in [reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation):

```
using AForge;

string expression = "$0 $0 $0 * * $1 $1 * + " + (Math.PI / 3) + " sin +";

// variables for the expression
double x = 4;
double y = 2;
double[] vars = new double[] { x, y };

// expression evaluation
double result = PolishExpression.Evaluate(expression, vars);

Console.WriteLine("Polish expression evaluation: " + result);
```

This yields the value 68.86602540378443. There's also no direct exponential operator, so I just multiplied x by itself three times. But you could use logaritms instead:

```
string expression = "$0 ln 3 * exp $1 ln 2 * exp + " + (Math.PI / 3) + " sin +";
```

You can also confirm that this is the same as you'd get in C# (note that you must convert 60 degrees to radians in order to use Math.sin):

```
double TestEvaluate(double x, double y)
{
    // x^3 + y^2 + sin60°
    // Note that Math.sin accepts radians, so we must convert 60°
    return Math.Pow(x, 3) + Math.Pow(y, 2) + Math.Sin((Math.PI / 180) * 60);
}

Console.WriteLine("C# evalution: " + TestEvaluate(x, y));
```

But yeah, I'd recommend using another library if you don't want to use polish notation in your expressions.

I also tried the code example above with "AForge.Math.Expression", but I don't believe this class exists in AForge.Math 2.2.5.

Comment: Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6f2yHj), if interested.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

It seems you need an expression parser. I decided to write one, that uses `System.Linq.Expression` for building expression trees. I started with the simple expression parser from https://github.com/toptensoftware/SimpleExpressionEngine and build from there.

### Example Code

First the fun stuff. Look at this test code

```
public static void TestSOExpr()
{            
    string expression = "x^3 + y^2 + sin(60°)";

    Parser parser = new Parser(expression);

    Console.WriteLine("Expression: ");
    Console.WriteLine(parser.Expression);

    Console.WriteLine("Arguments: ");
    foreach (var item in parser.Arguments)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    Func<double,double,double> f = parser.CompileBinary();
    double x = 4, y = 2;
    Console.WriteLine($"f({x},{y}) = {f(x, y)}");
}
```

with output

```text
Expression:
(((x ^ 3) + (y * y)) + sin((60 * 0.0174532925199433)))
Arguments:
x
y
f(4,2) = 68.8660254037844
```

The result is numerically correct. A lot of time was spent in trying to deal with `°` as a constant value with implied multiplication. I am happy with the results.

## Class Structure

To get there there are three classes needed

### Token

This information class holds the data extracted from the string such as names, values, operators, functions and parenthesis.

```
public enum TokenType
{
    EOF,
    Operator,
    StartBlock,
    EndBlock,
    Delimiter,
    Identifier,
    Number,
}

public readonly struct Token
{
    public static readonly Token Empty = new Token(TokenType.EOF, string.Empty, 0, 0);

    public Token(Token token, int level) : this()
    {
        this = token;
        Level = level;
    }

    Token(TokenType type, string symbol, double number, int level) : this()
    {
        Type = type;
        Symbol = symbol;
        Number = number;
        Level = level;
    }

    public static Token Operator(char symbol, int level = 0) => new Token(TokenType.Operator, symbol.ToString(), 0, level);
    public static Token StartBlock(char symbol, int level = 0) => new Token(TokenType.StartBlock, symbol.ToString(), 0, level);
    public static Token EndBlock(char symbol, int level = 0) => new Token(TokenType.EndBlock, symbol.ToString(), 0, level);
    public static Token Delimiter(char symbol, int level = 0) => new Token(TokenType.Delimiter, symbol.ToString(), 0, level);
    public static Token Identifier(string symbol, int level = 0) => new Token(TokenType.Identifier, symbol, 0, level);
    public static Token Value(double number, int level = 0) => new Token(TokenType.Number, string.Empty, number, level);

    public static Token operator +(Token token, int delta) => new Token(token, token.Level + delta);
    public static Token operator -(Token token, int delta) => new Token(token, token.Level - delta);

    public TokenType Type { get; }
    public string Symbol { get; }
    public double Number { get; }
    public int Level { get; }

    public bool IsEOF() => Type == TokenType.EOF;

    public bool IsOperator(char @operator) => IsOperator(out char op) && op == @operator;
    public bool IsOperator(out char @operator)
    {
        if (Type == TokenType.Operator)
        {
            @operator = Symbol[0];
            return true;
        }
        @operator = '\0';
        return false;
    }
    public bool IsIdentifier(string symbol) => IsIdentifier(out string x) && x.Equals(symbol);
    public bool IsIdentifier(out string symbol)
    {
        if (Type == TokenType.Identifier)
        {
            symbol = Symbol;
            return true;
        }
        symbol = string.Empty;
        return false;
    }
    public bool IsNumber(double value) => IsNumber(out double x) && x.Equals(value);
    public bool IsNumber(out double value)
    {
        if (Type == TokenType.Number)
        {
            value = Number;
            return true;
        }
        value = 0;
        return false;
    }
    public bool IsStartBlock(char delimiter) => IsStartBlock(out char sym) && sym == delimiter;
    public bool IsStartBlock(out char delimiter)
    {
        if (Type == TokenType.StartBlock)
        {
            delimiter = Symbol[0];
            return true;
        }
        delimiter = '\0';
        return false;
    }
    public bool IsEndBlock(char delimiter) => IsEndBlock(out char sym) && sym == delimiter;
    public bool IsEndBlock(out char delimiter)
    {
        if (Type == TokenType.EndBlock)
        {
            delimiter = Symbol[0];
            return true;
        }
        delimiter = '\0';
        return false;
    }
    public bool IsDelimiter(char delimiter) => IsDelimiter(out char sym) && sym == delimiter;
    public bool IsDelimiter(out char delimiter)
    {
        if (Type == TokenType.Delimiter)
        {
            delimiter = Symbol[0];
            return true;
        }
        delimiter = '\0';
        return false;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var tab = new string('\t', Level);
        switch (Type)
        {
            case TokenType.EOF:
                return $"{tab}{Type}";
            case TokenType.Operator:
            case TokenType.StartBlock:
            case TokenType.EndBlock:
            case TokenType.Delimiter:
            case TokenType.Identifier:
                return $"{tab}{Type}: {Symbol}";
            case TokenType.Number:
                return $"{tab}{Type}: {Number}";
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

### Tokenizer

The job of the tokenizer is to extract the `Token` from a string. This is done one step at a time with the `.MoveNext()` and `.Reset()` functions. At each step the `.Current` property holds the token information.

```
/// <summary>
/// Parses strings into Tokens for further processing.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Code taken from https://github.com/toptensoftware/SimpleExpressionEngine </remarks>
public class Tokenizer : IEnumerator<Token>, IEnumerable<Token>
{
    readonly string _expression;
    TextReader _reader;
    char _currentChar;

    public Tokenizer(string expression)
    {
        _expression = expression;
        Reset();
    }

    public Token Current { get; private set; }
    object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current { get => Current; }
    public IEnumerator<Token> GetEnumerator() => this;
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();


    public void Reset()
    {
        _reader = new StringReader(_expression);
        NextChar();
        //MoveNext();
    }
    // Read the next character from the input strem
    // and store it in _currentChar, or load '\0' if EOF
    void NextChar()
    {
        int ch = _reader.Read();
        _currentChar = ch < 0 ? '\0' : (char)ch;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        // Skip whitespace
        while (char.IsWhiteSpace(_currentChar))
        {
            NextChar();
        }

        switch (_currentChar)
        {
            case '\0':
                {
                    if (Current.Level > 0)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException();
                    }
                    Current = Token.Empty;
                    return false;
                }
            case '+':
            case '-':
            case '*':
            case '/':
            case '^':
            case '=':
                {
                    Current = Token.Operator(_currentChar, Current.Level);
                    NextChar();
                    return true;
                }
            case '(':
                {
                    Current = Token.StartBlock(_currentChar, Current.Level + 1);
                    NextChar();
                    return true;
                }
            case ')':
                {
                    Current = Token.EndBlock(_currentChar, Current.Level - 1);
                    NextChar();
                    return true;
                }
            case ';':
            case ',':
                {
                    Current = Token.Delimiter(_currentChar, Current.Level);
                    NextChar();
                    return true;
                }
        }
        if (char.IsDigit(_currentChar) || _currentChar == '.')
        {
            // Capture digits/decimal point
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            bool haveDecimalPoint = false;
            while (char.IsDigit(_currentChar) || (!haveDecimalPoint && _currentChar == '.'))
            {
                sb.Append(_currentChar);
                haveDecimalPoint = _currentChar == '.';
                NextChar();
            }

            // Parse it
            if (double.TryParse(sb.ToString(), NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double x))
            {
                Current = Token.Value(x, Current.Level);
                //Token = Token.Number;
                return true;
            }
        }
        // Identifier - starts with letter or underscore
        if (char.IsLetter(_currentChar) || _currentChar == '_' || _currentChar == '°')
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            // Accept letter, digit or underscore
            while (char.IsLetterOrDigit(_currentChar) || _currentChar == '_' || _currentChar == '°')
            {
                sb.Append(_currentChar);
                NextChar();
            }

            // Setup token
            Current = Token.Identifier(sb.ToString(), Current.Level);
            return true;
        }
        Current = Token.Empty;
        return false;
    }
    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    void Dispose(bool disposed)
    {
        if (disposed)
        {
            _reader.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

### Parser

This is the main class that recursively builds the expression tree. When the constructor is called, the resulting expression tree is stored in the `.Expression` property, as well as any required arguments in `.Arguments`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Parses a string into an <see cref="Expression"/> tree.
/// </summary>
public class Parser
{
    readonly Tokenizer _tokenizer;
    readonly Dictionary<string, ParameterExpression> _arguments;

    public Parser(string expression) : this(new Tokenizer(expression)) { }
    public Parser(Tokenizer tokenizer)
    {
        this._tokenizer = tokenizer;
        this._arguments = new Dictionary<string, ParameterExpression>();
        Expression = ParseTokens();
    }
    public Expression Expression { get; }
    public IReadOnlyList<ParameterExpression> Arguments => _arguments.Values.ToList();
    public Func<double> CompileNonary()
    {
        if (Arguments.Count == 0)
        {
            return Compile<Func<double>>();
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression has too many arguments.");
    }
    public Func<double, double> CompileUnary()
    {
        if (Arguments.Count == 1)
        {
            return Compile<Func<double, double>>();
        }
        if (Arguments.Count > 1)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression has too many arguments.");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression has too few arguments.");
        }
    }
    public Func<double, double, double> CompileBinary()
    {
        if (Arguments.Count == 2)
        {
            return Compile<Func<double, double, double>>();
        }
        if (Arguments.Count > 2)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression has too many arguments.");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression has too few arguments.");
        }
    }

    TFunc Compile<TFunc>() where TFunc : Delegate
    {
        ParameterExpression[] arguments = _arguments.Values.ToArray();
        return Expression.Lambda<TFunc>(Expression, arguments).Compile() as TFunc;
    }

    Expression ParseTokens()
    {
        _tokenizer.Reset();
        if (_tokenizer.MoveNext())
        {
            Expression expr = ParseEquals();
            // Check everything was consumed
            if (_tokenizer.Current.Type != TokenType.EOF)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected characters at end of expression");
            }

            return expr;
        }
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Expression");
    }

    Expression ParseEquals()
    {
        Expression lhs = ParseAddSubtract();

        while (true)
        {
            if (_tokenizer.Current.IsOperator('='))
            {
                _tokenizer.MoveNext();
                Expression rhs = ParseAddSubtract();

                lhs = Expression.Equal(lhs, rhs);
            }
            else
            {
                return lhs;
            }
        }
    }

    Expression ParseAddSubtract()
    {
        Expression lhs = ParseMulDivide();

        while (true)
        {
            if (_tokenizer.Current.IsOperator('+'))
            {
                _tokenizer.MoveNext();
                Expression rhs = ParseMulDivide();
                lhs = Expression.Add(lhs, rhs);
            }
            else if (_tokenizer.Current.IsOperator('-'))
            {
                _tokenizer.MoveNext();
                Expression rhs = ParseMulDivide();
                lhs = Expression.Subtract(lhs, rhs);
            }
            else
            {
                return lhs;
            }
        }
    }
    Expression ParseMulDivide()
    {
        Expression lhs = ParsePower();
        bool negate = false;
        if (lhs is ConstantExpression lex)
        {
            double x = Convert.ToDouble(lex.Value);
            if (x == 0)
            {
                return Expression.Constant(0.0);
            }
            else if (x == -1)
            {
                negate = true;
            }
            if (_tokenizer.Current.IsIdentifier(out string name))
            {
                // 60π - or example
                Expression rhs = ParseLeaf();
                return Expression.Multiply(lhs, rhs);
            }
        }


        while (true)
        {
            if (_tokenizer.Current.IsOperator('*'))
            {
                _tokenizer.MoveNext();
                Expression rhs = ParsePower();
                if (rhs is ConstantExpression rex)
                {
                    double y = Convert.ToDouble(rex.Value);
                    if (y == 0)
                    {
                        lhs = Expression.Constant(0.0);
                    }
                    else if (y == 1)
                    {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                    else if (y == -1)
                    {
                        negate = !negate;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lhs = Expression.Multiply(lhs, rhs);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lhs = Expression.Multiply(lhs, rhs);
                }
            }
            else if (_tokenizer.Current.IsOperator('/'))
            {
                _tokenizer.MoveNext();
                Expression rhs = ParsePower();
                if (rhs is ConstantExpression rex)
                {
                    double y = Convert.ToDouble(rex.Value);
                    if (y == 0)
                    {
                        lhs = Expression.Constant(double.PositiveInfinity);
                    }
                    else if (y == 1)
                    {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                    else if (y == -1)
                    {
                        negate = !negate;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lhs = Expression.Divide(lhs, rhs);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lhs = Expression.Divide(lhs, rhs);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return negate ? Expression.Negate(lhs) : lhs;
            }
        }

    }

    Expression ParsePower()
    {
        Expression lhs = ParseUnary();

        while (true)
        {
            if (_tokenizer.Current.IsOperator('^'))
            {
                _tokenizer.MoveNext();
                Expression rhs = ParseUnary();
                if (rhs is ConstantExpression cex)
                {
                    double x = Convert.ToDouble(cex.Value);
                    if (x == 0)
                    {
                        return Expression.Constant(1.0);
                    }

                    if (x == 1)
                    {
                        return lhs;
                    }

                    if (x == -1)
                    {
                        return Expression.Divide(Expression.Constant(1.0), lhs);
                    }

                    if (x == 2)
                    {
                        return Expression.Multiply(lhs, lhs);
                    }
                }
                lhs = Expression.Power(lhs, rhs);
            }
            else
            {
                return lhs;
            }
        }
    }

    Expression ParseUnary()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_tokenizer.Current.IsOperator('+'))
            {
                // ignore unary +
                _tokenizer.MoveNext();
                continue;
            }
            if (_tokenizer.Current.IsOperator('-'))
            {
                _tokenizer.MoveNext();
                Expression rhs = ParseUnary();
                if (rhs is UnaryExpression uex)
                {
                    if (uex.NodeType == ExpressionType.Negate)
                    {
                        return uex.Operand;
                    }
                }
                return Expression.Negate(rhs);
            }

            return ParseLeaf();
        }
    }

    private Expression ParseLeaf()
    {
        if (_tokenizer.Current.IsNumber(out double x))
        {
            _tokenizer.MoveNext();
            return Expression.Constant(x);
        }
        if (_tokenizer.Current.IsStartBlock('('))
        {
            _tokenizer.MoveNext();

            Expression node = ParseAddSubtract();

            if (!_tokenizer.Current.IsEndBlock(')'))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Mismatched Parenthesis.");
            }

            _tokenizer.MoveNext();

            return node;
        }
        if (_tokenizer.Current.IsIdentifier(out string name))
        {
            _tokenizer.MoveNext();

            if (_tokenizer.Current.IsStartBlock('('))
            {
                // function call
                _tokenizer.MoveNext();

                // Parse arguments
                List<Expression> arguments = new List<Expression>();

                while (true)
                {
                    Expression node = ParseAddSubtract();
                    arguments.Add(node);

                    if (_tokenizer.Current.IsDelimiter(','))
                    {
                        _tokenizer.MoveNext();
                        continue;
                    }
                    // end of arguments
                    break;
                }

                if (!_tokenizer.Current.IsEndBlock(')'))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Mismatched Parenthesis.");
                }

                _tokenizer.MoveNext();


                MethodInfo f = typeof(MathFunctions).GetMethod(name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

                if (f != null)
                {
                    switch (arguments.Count)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            return Expression.Call(f);
                        case 1:
                            return Expression.Call(f, arguments[0]);
                        case 2:
                            return Expression.Call(f, arguments[0], arguments[1]);
                        default:
                            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Too many arguments for function {name}.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unknown function {name}.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (MathFunctions.knownConstants.ContainsKey(name))
                {
                    // named constant
                    return Expression.Constant(MathFunctions.knownConstants[name]);
                }
                // variable
                if (!_arguments.ContainsKey(name))
                {
                    // add to list of arguments
                    _arguments.Add(name, Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), name));
                }
                return _arguments[name];
            }
        }
        if (!_tokenizer.Current.IsEOF())
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unexpected token {_tokenizer.Current}");
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

### MathFunctions

The parser depends on a utility function to provide method bodies for math functions. Most are wrappers around the `Math` class, but some are new. The names are lowercase to match with any functions called in the parsed string.

```
public static class MathFunctions
{
    internal static readonly Random rng = new Random();
    internal static readonly Dictionary<string, double> knownConstants =
        new Dictionary<string, double>()
        {
            ["pi"] = Math.PI,
            ["π"] = Math.PI,
            ["e"] = Math.E,
            ["Φ"] = (1 + Math.Sqrt(5)) / 2,
            ["°"] = Math.PI / 180,
            ["deg"] = Math.PI / 180,
            ["rad"] = 180 / Math.PI,
            ["rpm"] = 2 * Math.PI / 60,
        };
 
    public static double rand() => rng.NextDouble();
    public static double abs(double x) => Math.Abs(x);
    public static double sqr(double x) => x * x;
    public static double sqrt(double x) => Math.Sqrt(x);
    public static double sign(double x) => (double)Math.Sign(x);
    public static double floor(double x) => Math.Floor(x);
    public static double round(double x) => Math.Round(x);
    public static double exp(double x) => Math.Exp(x);
    public static double log(double x) => Math.Log(x);
    public static double sin(double x) => Math.Sin(x);
    public static double cos(double x) => Math.Cos(x);
    public static double tan(double x) => Math.Tan(x);
    public static double asin(double x) => Math.Asin(x);
    public static double acos(double x) => Math.Acos(x);
    public static double atan(double x) => Math.Atan(x);
    public static double sinh(double x) => Math.Sinh(x);
    public static double cosh(double x) => Math.Cosh(x);
    public static double tanh(double x) => Math.Tanh(x);
    public static double asinh(double x) => Math.Log(Math.Sqrt(x * x + 1) + x);
    public static double acosh(double x) => Math.Log(Math.Sqrt(x * x - 1) + x);
    public static double atanh(double x) => -Math.Log((1 - x) / (1 + x)) / 2;
    
    public static double pow(double x, double y) => Math.Pow(x, y);
    public static double atan2(double dy, double dx) => Math.Atan2(dy, dx);
    public static double min(double x, double y) => Math.Min(x, y);
    public static double max(double x, double y) => Math.Max(x, y);
}
```

As a final note the parser also supports some named constants

```
"pi" = Math.PI,
"π" = Math.PI,
"e" = Math.E,
"Φ" = (1 + Math.Sqrt(5)) / 2,
"°" = Math.PI / 180,
"deg" = Math.PI / 180,
"rad" = 180 / Math.PI,
"rpm" = 2 * Math.PI / 60,
```

Such that inputs such as `6π` and `60°` and `1000rpm` are supported.

### Compiling

The .NET Expression class has a `.Compile()` method that can be used to turn the expression into a function. Wrappers around this method exists in the parser such that `CompileUnary()` and `CompileBinary()` produce functions of the form `f(x)` and `f(x,y)` respectively with arguments and return types that of double numbers.

From the example code above this is demonstrated with

```
    var f = parser.CompileBinary();
    double x = ...
    double y = ...
    double z = f(x, y);
```